# Background Worker is not Working With Oracle Connection

Tags: .net, wpf, backgroundworker

I have strange problem I want to fetch records from Oracle(Online Db) and insert and update to MySQL database which is offline Database that if a failover the MYSQL database starts function. I have to update the main records from Oracle to MySql so that if the Offline database starts in the game it has all relevant synched data in it.

I have wrote the code with BackgroundWorker Class so that I can keep it in a separate thread 
Following is the code please review

Code

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data;

namespace HospitalSystem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for HospitalSync.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class HospitalSync : Window
    {
       public BackgroundWorker Worker;
       public int TotalRecords;

        public HospitalSync()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int CalculatePercentage(int Current)
        {
            int Percentage = (int) (Current / TotalRecords) * 100;
            return Percentage;
        }

        public void SyncDataFromKPT(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MedEntities Db = new MedEntities();

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(Db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
            {
                DataTable RecordsToUpdateTable = new DataTable();
                string SqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM medsec.vu_registration_modify";
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(SqlCommand, connection))
                {
                    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(SqlCommand, connection);
                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    adapter.Fill(RecordsToUpdateTable);
                    if (RecordsToUpdateTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= RecordsToUpdateTable.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            RecCountTotal.Content = j + 1;
                            CalculatePercentage(j);
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        public void ProcessCompleted(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        public void InitializeWorker()
        {
            Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            Worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(SyncDataFromKPT);
            Worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProcessCompleted);
            Worker.RunWorkerAsync(Worker);  
        }   

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeWorker();   
        }
    }
}
```

At this point `MedEntities Db = new MedEntities();`  goes file after the Using block it doesn't execute the code not even if I put breakpoints.

Please guide me how to make the code function

Comment: Do you get an error message? Is Db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString valid? I suspect that the Connection property needs to be set up first. You should try to acquire the connection string in another way (no connection string, no connection, so you can't use the connection to get the connection string).

Comment: I have fetched the connection string in my earlier application using the same logic and it worked as a charm.

Comment: @Markus when I remove the whole using block it executes

Comment: Register the [RunWorkerCompletedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) of the BackgroundWorker and check the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs if it contains any Exceptions or Errors

Comment: @Markus You were right. There was an error with the Oracle.DataAccess Library i was working on the 64bit application and the DLL was for 32 Bit Application. I changed the project properties to 32 bit application and it worked as a Charm. Thank you for your Help

Comment: @ShakoorAlam mark it as resolved then.

Answer (score 0):

This Question is resolved with the help of @Markus.
Thank you

It was an issue of the Platform I was using the 32 bit Client Library and was debugging on 64 bit.